# Incompatible pointer type and struct issues

Tags: c, pointers

```
#define HASH_SIZE 5

// prototype
int hash(char *word);

// counter
int counter;

// node
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// hash table
struct node *hashtable[HASH_SIZE];
  bool
load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open the dictionary
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if(dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return false;
    }

    // set all values in the hash table to null
    for(int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // set the counter to 0
    counter = 0;

    // iterate through the words in the dictionary
    while (!feof(dict))
    {
        //declare a node
        node *n = malloc( sizeof(node) );

        // copy the word into the node
        fscanf(dict, "%s", n.word);

        // hash the word
        int hash_value = hash(n.word);

        // start saving addresses to the hashtable
        n.next = hashtable[hash_value];
        hashtable[hash_value] = &n;

        // that's one more!
        counter++;
    }


    fclose(dict);

    return true;
}
```

For the following lines:

```
        //declare a node
    node *n = malloc( sizeof(node) );
```

```
// hash the word
    int hash_value = hash(n.word);

    // start saving addresses to the hashtable
    n.next = hashtable[hash_value];
    hashtable[hash_value] = &n;r code here
```

I receive the following error messages:

> dictionary.c: In function 'load':
>   dictionary.c:112:29: error: request for member 'word' in something not a structure or union
>   dictionary.c:135:32: error: request for member 'word' in something not a structure or union
>   dictionary.c:138:10: error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
>   dictionary.c:139:31: error: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]

What's the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really simple:

```
node *n = malloc( sizeof(node) );
fscanf(dict, "%s", n.word);
```

`n` is a pointer to a `node`, but `n.word` implies that `n` itself is a `node`. For a pointer, the syntax is a little different.

```
fscanf(dict, "%s", n->word);
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do I solve this problem, though?  hashtable[hash_value] = &n;  gives me the error: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Comment: I don't know; I don't see the declaration of `hashtable` anywhere, so I don't know what data type it is!

Comment: Oops!  Let me add that in:
struct node *hashtable[HASH_SIZE];

Comment: Ah, I see now!  I should put:  hashtable[hash_value] = n; because, as you said, n is a pointer, not a node.  Anyhow, thanks for the help!